# Why Android's Storage folder is /data/data/?

Tags: android

Why there are two consecutive `data`?
Is there any intention or unavoidable reason on the Android architecture?

Just out of curiosity...

Comment: Search on _Google_ for that.

Comment: @M D I have searched but what I found is "How to access /data/data/..." or "Where is /data/data/..."  What I am wondering is why the path name is /data/data/, and not just `/data/` or something more readable/simple path?

Comment: It's related to `Linux`. becoz in android beck end is `Linux Kernal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because

The first data folder can be opened without root access, 
the data folder inside it is not visible without root access.

So

one to show for guys without root access without any contents.
second for guys with root access.

**haha this is android engineers personal decision, no need to know more reason**